# My website leads the user to a new page using the PHP GET method

Tags: php, redirect, get

My website has a feature when a user can submit a link to the website. This link is submitted using a form that submits to a php page using the GET method. My issue is that when the user clicks "Submit" on the form the URL changes and the user is taken to a black white page. Is there a method of submitting data without the redirecting to a new page?

the submit form:

```
<form action="submitvid.php" method="get">
<font size="+1">Submit A Video: </font>
<input type="text" name="submittedurl" />
<input type="submit" />
```

the php page:

```
$videourl=$_GET["submittedurl"];
```

Comment: You can use ajax methods to submit a form without page reload.
Refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

From your code, i feel that you are redirecting the user to submitvid.php which might be different from where the above form exists.

If not, then you have a header() thing in your PHP code that redirects to a blank page

Answer (score 1):

**Considering your form page is PHP:** On same page leave action empty `action=""` server will assume submission on same page and you can put a check at top:

```
if(isset($_GET["submittedurl"])) {
     //save url here
}
```

**Considering your form page is Simple HTML:** In submitvid.php after saving url you can redirect back user to old page. `header("Location: index.html")`

Answer (score 1):

Either do the process in the same page (ex: `index.php`), so you'll put this a the begining of the file:

```
// index.php file

if ( isset($_GET["submittedurl"]) ){
    $videourl=$_GET["submittedurl"];
    // do everything you want to the url
}
```

or redirect from the `submitvid.php` page after the work is done using `header()`

```
//submitvid.php file

$videourl=$_GET["submittedurl"];
// what you want to do with $videourl
header('location: index.php');
```

or use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

you can submit it to the same page that you are , or you can use AJAX.
or you can submit it to a new page, and you redirect it again using :

```
<?php header("location: example.php"); ?>
```